# How to overload Lua string subscript operator?

Tags: string, lua, operator-overloading

This:

```
debug.getmetatable("").__index = function (s, i) return s:sub(i, i) end
```

and this:

```
debug.getmetatable("").__index = _proc_lua_read
```

does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
debug.getmetatable("").__index = function (s, i) return string.sub(s,i,i) end
```

Note that by redefining `__index` for strings in that way, you lose the ability to call methods on strings: note how the code does not call `s:sub`. For a better solution that avoids that, see http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2007-11/msg00619.html . Or set `__call` instead:

```
getmetatable("").__call = string.sub
```