# Parse String in Lua

Tags: parsing, lua

I've found a lot of ways to split a string at a comma in Lua, but that's not quite what I'm looking for. I need to be able to do the following: I have the argument `ABC` being in as a string, and I need to be able to extract just the `A`, `B`, and the `C`. How do I do this? I keep hoping something like this will work:

```
x = tostring(ABC)
x[1]
x[2]
x[3]
```

Comment: Is there some kind of fixed format? I.e. is it always three characters? Or is there some kind of delimiting character?

Also what version of Lua are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to get the substrings of an index, this should work in most version of Lua:

```
x = 'ABC'
print (string.sub(x, 1, 1))  -- 'A'
print (string.sub(x, 2, 2))  -- 'B'
print (string.sub(x, 3, 3))  -- 'C'
```

In Lua 5.1 onward, according to this [doc](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringIndexing), you can do the following:

```
getmetatable('').__index = function(str,i) return string.sub(str,i,i) end

x = 'ABC'
print (x[1])  -- 'A'
print (x[2])  -- 'B'
print (x[3])  -- 'C'
```

Comment: It's better to preserve old `__index` metamethod for strings: `function(str,i) return type(i)=="number" and str:sub(i,i) or str[i] end`

Comment: In my previous comment `str[i]` should be replaced with `string[i]` to avoid stack overflow :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can also set a *call* metamethod for strings:

> getmetatable("").__call = string.sub

Then this works:

```
for i=1,4 do
        print(i,x(i),x(i,i))
end
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685920/how-to-overload-lua-string-subscript-operator/5685971

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy. Just ***iterate***.

**(Assume you're using version 5.1 of Lua)**

---

***Code :***

```
str = "xyz"
for i = 1, #str do
    local c = str:sub(i,i)
    print(c)
end
```

***Output :***

```
$lua main.lua
x
y
z
```

---

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/uKRIwVZBqaKySolLAQjS8osUMoEihjoKyiC5lHywMAjk5Ccn5igkAyWBElbFpUkamTqZmnDpgqLMvBKNZIhAal7K//8A)

---

Or, as [@tonypdmtr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3735873/tonypdmtr) said in comment :

```
for s in s:gmatch '.' do print(s) end
```

Comment: Or simpler: `for s in s:gmatch '.' do print(s) end`

Answer (score 0):

Without confusing metatables:

```
function getCharacters(str)
local x = {}
for i=1, str:len(), 1 do
table.insert(x, str:sub(i, i))
end
return x
end
```

With this function, no matter how long your string is, you will always have a table filled with it's characters in it :)